# Розбивати парк чи садити парк?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

В університеті я вчила, що парк розбивають згідно [розбивочного креслення](https://platonstroy.com.ua/rozbuvochne-kreslennya-dulyank-cze.html).

Проте на сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/posadutu-park) вказано, що парк можна лише посадити.
[image]

Є декілька коментарів на захист словосполучення "розбивати парк".

В СУМ-11 зазначено:

> [Розбивати](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozbyvaty) 12. Розміряти, розплановувати ділянки землі. *— На нашу
> думку, можна було б зробити так: розбити оцю площу перед Раківкою ..за
> принципом шахівниці* (Микола Трублаїні, I, 1955, 67)
>
> //  Садити що-небудь на певній ділянці землі після розпланування. *На
> майданчику для відпочинку розбивають квітники з однорічних і
> багаторічних квітів та квітучих кущів — спіреї, жасміну тощо* (Хлібороб
> України, 9, 1964, 24); *— Вирізуємо з поля шматок землі задля двору,
> громадським заходом збудуємо будиночок, розіб'ємо садок...* (Панас
> Мирний, IV, 1955, 327).

Отже, як правильно говорити та писати: "розбивати" чи "садити" парк?

Comment: Припускаю, що «розбивати парк» може належати до професійної лексики, а «садити парк» — до загальної. (Також припускаю, що _розбиття_ може мати на увазі більшу кількість процесів, ніж _саджання_: _саджання_ включає лише безпосередньо посадку дерев, а _розбиття_ — також проектування, підготовку ділянки, облаштування доріжок/лавок/тощо й т.ін.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заглянемо на [уроки державної мови](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/printer--friendly//frazeologiya) професора Пономарева:

> В усному й писемному мовленні нерідко чуємо й читаємо кумедні з
>   погляду лексико-фразеологічних норм української мови вислови: «На
>   місці звалища мешканці молодого міста розбили парк; Страйкарі розбили
>   намети перед міськрадою» та ін. Дієслово розбити є синонімом слів
>   знищити, розтрощити, роз’юшити тощо. Воно входить до таких
>   словосполучень, як розбити лоба, розбити (розірвати) кайдани, розбити
>   серце і т. ін. **Щодо парку або саду треба використовувати більш підхожі
>   лексеми — посадити, насадити, виростити**: «Я гостро відчуваю запах
>   саду, що я посадив» (Ю. Яновський). Намети теж не розбивають, а
>   ставлять або напинають (як у прямому, так і в переносному значенні):
>   «Над покрівлями будинків осінні хмари нап’яли сизий намет» (О.
>   Копиленко).

Про це пише і на [цьому сайті](https://community.languagetool.org/rule/show/ROZBYVATY_NAMET?lang=uk&subId=1) і на [Словпедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53408/27247.html) (інформація з газети Хрещатик). У тій же газеті Хрещатик читаємо пояснення:

> Величезна кількість таких помилок пояснюється тим, що тривалий час
>   серед багатьох українців українська мова не виконувала функції рідної
>   мови, якою думають, спілкуються в усіх сферах життя, мріють і снять,
>   радіють і сумують. Вона була непотрібним додатком до іншої,
>   престижнішої мови. У рамках політики зближення націй та злиття мов, що
>   досягла апогею під час застою 70–80-х, слова, не схожі на російські,
>   викидали з нашої мови або оголошували діалектними, застарілими,
>   штучними, не зрозумілими народові. З академічного Інституту
>   мовознавства до видавництв і редакцій надходили списки заборонених
>   слів та висловів (на зразок либонь, робітня, красне письменство), які
>   при редагуванні наказувалося вилучати з оригінальних та перекладних
>   творів.
>
> Має рацію Олександр Пономарів: тривале зросійщення українців призвело
>   до втрати дороговказів у користуванні рідною мовою. Досі багато хто з
>   мовців залюбки вживає слова благополуччя, відправлятися, діючий,
>   добросовісний, економити, значимий, корзина, настійливий, прийомна,
>   протиріччя, початкуючий і майже цілковито ігнорує далеко кращі
>   синонімічні відповідники добробут, вирушати, дійовий, сумлінний,
>   заощаджувати, значущий, кошик, наполегливий, приймальня, суперечність,
>   початківець.
>
> Відомо, що кальки мають використовуватися лише тоді, коли у своїй мові
>   немає потрібних лексем для позначення того або того предмета, істоти,
>   явища. Але ці кальки, яких “побутує” у нас сила-силенна (і явних, і
>   примаскованих росіянізмів, з не властивими для української мови
>   чужомовними значеннями), як звичайнісінькі дублети наших питомих слів
>   не тільки відтісняють їх на другий план, а й узагалі витискують із
>   загального вжитку

Знову повертаємося до історії. [СУМ-11](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) було видано у 1970–1980, тому можливо, якісь скальковані вислови туди і потрапили (крім того, якщо дивитися на приклади, які подаються в СУМі, то можна побачити, що всі вони взяті із творів, які виходили коли Україна знаходилася у складі СРСР, а російська мова була домінантною, тому можливо деякі письменники і використовували кальку).

Також на цьому [форумі](https://ua-mova.livejournal.com/898407.html) заперечують правильність вислову "розбити парк".

Який висновок можемо зробити?

Гадаю, що казати чи писати "розбити парк" можна, бо все таки ми знаходимо такий варіант в СУМ11, а це є офіційне джерело. Проте, потрібно врахувати, що навіть там можуть бути помилки (так само як і може помилятися професор Пономарів), а тому щоб точно уникнути кальки можна використовувати "**посадити/насадити/виростити парк**", або ж може навіть "[**закласти**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakladaty) парк".